# How to determine the angle a camera has to be at to image a desired scene, given the camera parameters?

Tags: optics, vision, imaging

Reviewing old material I learned years ago, having a hard time rewrapping my head around the relationships in capturing images from a camera.

Imagine a scenario with the camera placed on the ground (potentially elevated at some angle).  We have a sensor size of `3.6 by 4.8 mm`, a resolution of `640 x 480 px`, a 10 cm tall object that we want to be `50 px` in the image.  We have a focal length of `3 mm` and the image is 1 m away.

How do we determine the angle that the camera has to be at to capture the image with these properties?

Answer (score 2):

This is the third question you've posted, all related to simple imaging problems. If you are indeed interested in understanding this material you are reading, I suggest that you first read any basic book about optics. There you'll find how to make simple ray diagrams that will enable you to answer all of these questions by yourself, and understand where do the answers come from.